# Where are jplephem ephemerides api documented?

Tags: pyephem, skyfield

I am working on what is likely a unique use case - I want to use Skyfield to do some calculations on a hypothetical star system.  I would do this by creating my own ephemeris, and using that instead of the actual one.  The problem i am finding is that I cannot find documentation on the API to replace the ephemerides with my own.

Is there documentation?  Is skyfield something flexible enough to do what I am trying?

Edit:
To clarify what I am asking, I understand that I will have to do some gravitational modeling (and I am perfectly willing to configure every computer, tablet, cable box and toaster in this house to crunch on those numbers for a few days :), but before I really dive into it, I wanted to know what the data looks like.  If it is just a module with a number of named numpy 2d arrays... that makes it rather easy, but I didn't see this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPL-issued ephemerides used by Skyfield, like DE405 and DE406 and DE421, simply provide a big table of numbers for each planet. For example, Neptune’s position might be specified in 7-day increments, where for each 7-day period from the beginning to the end of the ephemeris the table provides a set of polynomial coefficients that can be used to estimate Neptune's position at any moment from the beginning to the end of that 7-day period. The polynomials are designed, if I understand correctly, so that their first and second derivative meshes smoothly with the previous and following 7-day polynomial at the moment where one ends and the next begins.

The JPL generates these huge tables by taking the positions of the planets as we have recorded them over human history, taking the rules by which we think an ideal planet would move given gravitational theory, the drag of the solar wind, the planet's own rotation and dynamics, its satellites, and so forth, and trying to choose a “real path” for the planet that agrees with theory while passing as close to the actual observed positions as best as it can.

This is a big computational problem that, I take it, requires quite a bit of finesse. If you cannot match all of the observations perfectly — which you never can — then you have to decide which ones to prioritize, and which ones are probably not as accurate to begin with.

For a hypothetical system, you are going to have to start from scratch by doing (probably?) a gravitational dynamics simulation. There are, if I understand correctly, several possible approaches that are documented in the various textbooks on the subject. Whichever one you choose should let you generate *x*,*y*,*z* positions for your hypothetical planets, and you would probably instantiate these in Skyfield as ICRS positions if you then wanted to use Skyfield to compute distances, observations, or to draw diagrams.

Though I have not myself used it, I have seen good reviews of:

[http://www.amazon.com/Solar-System-Dynamics-Carl-Murray/dp/0521575974](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521575974)